# How to create a star shape design in ionic4 (HTML & CSS)?

Tags: angular, user-interface, ionic-framework, dynamic, ionic4

I want to create a star shape div design for my mobile application which is building using ionic4.

Here is the design I want to create.

[image]

This design should create dynamically. I mean if user add new favourites item. Then it also should listed in a similar way.

I am trying to get a Favourite List for Database and trying to use `*ngFor` to generate the UI.

I have a small idea to create this UI.

1. First create a angular ionic component and place icon and text. We can pass data by using `@Input()`.
2. Second create a another angular ionic component which can generate above UI design.

If you can suggest more effective way. It is highly appreciated.

Comment: Why not using [this](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/fab) ?

Comment: @Lud That's a good solution. But can we have more items. And remove those animations?

Comment: @Lud we can't add more than 4 items? Can we?